# How to manage null geometric field wising SqlGeometry type?

Tags: c#, sqlgeometry

I was trying to get  geometric value from DB.

```
SqlGeometry g = new SqlGeometry();
g.Read(new BinaryReader(reader.GetSqlBytes(2).Stream));
```

this code does not work when the field is null, gives exception.
I'm struggling to find a solution.
Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: `SqlDataReader.IsDBNull` is a thing.

Comment: `if (!reader.IsDBNull(2)) g.Read.....`